# needs of /boot, what is the problem without /boot

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For what using /boot and /tmp Partition in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131524/for-what-using-boot-and-tmp-partition-in-ubuntu)

I don't know what is the need of

```
/boot
```

What is the problem doing partition without /boot?

I decided to create a "**5 GB /boot**" partition on my 20 GB hard disk.